# Oracle SQL Reg Exp check email

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to check if an email address fits a pattern:

-Only letters, numbers, and '.' or '_' symbols.

-The last part (ex: .com) must contain between 2 and 4 letters.

This is my Reg Exp: `'[a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}'`

The problem is that it accepts symbols like %, and .commmm is accepted as the last part. How could I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problems are actually two here:

- You are using an unescaped `.` outside the character class that may match *any* symbol (but a newline)
- You are not using anchors `^` and `$`, and thus you may match substring inside a larger string.

Use

```
'^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._]+[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'
 ^                             ^^^             ^
```

When you place a `.` into a pair of square brackets, you match a literal period.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need `^` and `$` to specify the beginning and end of the string:

```
 '^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'
```

You might want to slightly adjust the rules so the email and domain cannot start with a period:

```
 '^\w[a-zA-Z0-9.]*@\w[a-zA-Z0-9.]*.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'
```